# Django: exclude objects while checking ManyToMany Field

Tags: django

I'm sure someone already asked similar question but I couldn't figure out how I can do what I want to achieve. Please modify the title if there is a better title.

What I want to do is like this

```
class Game(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models>CASCADE)


class User(AbstractUser):
    block_users = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

I want to list `Game` obejcts but want to exclude if `self.request.user` is in  the parent's (`created_by`) ManyToManyField `block_users`

I tried to do this but it didn't work.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Game.objects.exclude(created_by__block_users=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Try `.exclude(created_by__in=self.request.user.block_users)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying based on the created by users, we can try from the point of view of the logged in user.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Game.objects.exclude(created_by__in=self.request.user.blocked_users.all())
```